# Redirect to another page using 301 redirect not working

Tags: php, .htaccess

I want to do a redirection from one static page to another page. This is the URL that I want to be redirected from

```
http://www.appmonks.net/post.php/66/5-Open-Source-iOS-Libraries-For-App-Development./?id=66&title=5-Open-Source-iOS-Libraries-For-App-Development
```

to below url

```
http://www.appmonks.net/id/66/What-is-CodeIgniter-?/
```

I have added below code in .htaccess, but it seems to be not working.

```
Redirect 301 /post.php/66/5-Open-Source-iOS-Libraries-For-App-Development./?id=66&title=5-Open-Source-iOS-Libraries-For-App-Development http://www.appmonks.net/
```

Comment: Please look into the working solution given by me along with an online example.In case it solved your problem do accept it so that other SO user can benefit from it.

Comment: Swagatika: it looks like @AnkitRastogi has asked you to review their answer. Please do so now, given that you have signed in again and have asked a new question. While it is not mandatory to reply, it is certainly polite to do so.

Answer (score 1):

Use the below rewrite rule

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} id=66&title=5-Open-Source-iOS-Libraries-For-App-Development
RewriteRule (.*) "http://www.appmonks.net/id/66/What-is-CodeIgniter-?/"  [L,R=301,NE]
```

I have tested it in online htaccess testing tool

[results of the above rule](https://htaccess.madewithlove.be?share=eb49e7c9-47c1-50fe-9bd3-4f4bd744a76d)

The problem with the redirect rule is the `? mark` character in the url due to which redirect and rewrite rule is not working.

Also do ensure that `mod_rewrite` is included.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
header("Location: http://www.appmonks.net/id/66/What-is-CodeIgniter-?/");
```

just put this code before anything is output.